# Django runs successfully at localhost but 500 on AWS EB

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, internal-server-error

I just tried writing a simple Django application hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I can run the server successfully on my localhost. However, when I deploy it on EB, it failed with an 500 error.

Here is my project tree

```
.   
├── README.md   
├── db.sqlite3   
├── djangosite   
│   ├── __init__.py   
│   ├── settings.py   
│   ├── urls.py   
│   └── wsgi.py   
├── intro   
│   ├── __init__.py   
│   ├── admin.py   
│   ├── apps.py   
│   ├── migrations   
│   │   └── __init__.py   
│   ├── models.py   
│   ├── tests.py   
│   └── views.py   
├── manage.py   
├── requirement.txt   
└── templates   
    └── index.html
```

I didn't find the log with the correct time in the logs. Usually 500 means there may be something wrong with my codes. But it runs well if I start the server locally

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

I tried to us `eb ssh` to login the instance and find there is no `django` in `/opt/current/app` where my codes sit.

But I truly add Django==1.9.8 to `requirement.txt`. It seems eb do not installed `django`. It is also not in `/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

Comment: Did you install django on the server?  for example, what does `python -c 'import django; print django.get_version()` return?

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment)

I'm assuming that you're application starts at all on the production server(you don't mention whether is does).

Did you change Debug=False on the production server? Then uncaught exceptions in cause a 500 response. While having Debug=True in development(locally) returns you the Debug screen.